# how to print data in nice clean way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am learning python 3.

I imported dataset from sklearn. 
When I print it, it looks weird. 
What command should I use in order to see data clearly organized: column, rows.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_boston()
print(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand that the object data that you created have these attributes according to the [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html):

- `data['data']` is an `len()` 506 array. Each element has 13 other elements so, doing `len(data['data'][1])` actually returns 13.
- You can see the `data['feature_names']` as the "column names" here, it have 13 string elements.

Now, with that info, you can understand that to print a table you can print a header with the `data['feature_names']` and print the rows inside `data['data']`.

Grabbing this [tabular data snippet in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data), you can print it nicely using the tabulate module.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print tabulate(data['data'], headers=data['feature_names'])
```

This is the result:

```
CRIM     ZN    INDUS    CHAS     NOX     RM    AGE      DIS    RAD    TAX    PTRATIO       B    LSTAT
0.00632   18       2.31       0  0.538   6.575   65.2   4.09        1    296       15.3  396.9      4.98
0.02731    0       7.07       0  0.469   6.421   78.9   4.9671      2    242       17.8  396.9      9.14
0.02729    0       7.07       0  0.469   7.185   61.1   4.9671      2    242       17.8  392.83     4.03
0.03237    0       2.18       0  0.458   6.998   45.8   6.0622      3    222       18.7  394.63     2.94
```

Sorry if I interpreted the data in an incorrect way, I don't understood what 'Load and return the Boston house-prices data-set' stands for, but, this should help you print the data in a tabular way.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has prettier printing.  Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in data:
    print("{: >20} {: >20} {: >20}".format(*row))
```

This will produce a layout with three columns.